# What constitutes a "save"?

Tags: overwatch-2

Overwatch 2 now tracks a stat called "players saved", with a notification when you save someone (or when you get saved by someone else). However, with some exceptions, it's not entirely clear what constitutes a "save". The obvious examples are abilities that grant immortality or immunity, but from what I've observed it seems to be more complicated than that. How do you earn a save in Overwatch 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to Marblr](https://youtu.be/BdJvv6016aU), a save is awarded in cases where a player receives damage and survives. The game checks to see what that player's health was 2 seconds ago. If the damage received would have been lethal 2 seconds ago, then a potential save occurred. The game checks for healing events within the window, and applies save credit if:

1. The savior is not the same as the victim (except for special case 1 below)
2. The savior has not saved this victim within 5 seconds
3. The savior provided the victim with at least 50 healing within the window
4. The victim survives for 0.5 seconds after the save occurred

Saves can be earned by any hero with a healing ability, including Soldier 76's Biotic Field, Sombra's Hack, and Genji's Deflect. Saves can also be earned with abilities that provide overhealth according to the same rules as regular healing, including Junker Queen's Commanding Shout, Lucio's Sound Barrier, and Brigitte's Rally.

Additionally, a save is awarded in the following special cases:

1. If Baptiste's Immortality Field prevents a death
2. If Mercy's Resurrection reverses a death
3. If Lifeweaver's Life Grip mitigates lethal damage

Kiriko's Protection Suzu does not award saves, since it makes targets intangible rather than invulnerable.

Answer (score 6):

I’ve been wondering too and I think I have figured it out.

Hypothetically, let's say someone is at 20 HP and you heal them back to 60 and in the next few seconds they take 20 damage, they would have been dead. So a "save" is basically if you heal them just before they would have died.

Comment: Baptiste's and Kiriko's invulns probably also count.